# set Check to treeView checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, treeview

I have a `TreeView` that each item has a different code.
User can check 5 items and save them. Then I have a list of treeView's nodes code.
I want to show the checked items in form load to the user.
But my code doesn't work. 
can anybody help me?

This is my code :

```
private void chechTreeViewItems(List<int> remID)
    {
        foreach ( System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode item in this.tvRemark.Nodes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < remID.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt16(item.Tag)== remID[i])
                {
                     item.Checked = true;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

I think this code can't trace child nodes.

Comment: Are you writing WPF or winform app?

Comment: Is your Nodes list flat tree or hierarchical structure?

Comment: hierarchical, but just one parent and around 20 child

Comment: If all children have the same parent, then all you have to do is run your loop on `this.tvRemark.Nodes[0].Nodes`, and perhaps also check `this.tvRemark.Nodes[0]`.

Comment: Then you can't just access all the child nodes with one for loop. You have to loop recursively. If you want example for how to loop recursively, please ask me.

Comment: Have a look at this to recursive loop:http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/196856/C-NET-Treeview-Node-Checked

Comment: I changed it , but in the check part it give always the parent tag.          if (Convert.ToInt16(this.tvRemark.Nodes[0].Tag) == remID[i])                 this.tvRemark.Nodes[0].Tag   is always the parent tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one root node which has several sub nodes (only one level) then you don't need recursion here. Just set the root node in your foreach loop correctly:

```
private void chechTreeViewItems(List<int> remID)
{
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode item in this.tvRemark.Nodes[0].Nodes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < remID.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt16(item.Tag) == remID[i])
            {
                item.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
private void ChechTreeViewItems(List<int> remId)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode item in this.Nodes)
        {
            if (remId.Contains(item.Tag))
            {
                item.IsChecked = true;
            }

            if (item.Children != null)
            {
                this.CheckChildTreeNodes(item.Children, remId);
            }
        }
    }
```

And call re-cursive `CheckChildTreeNodes` method to ensure, child nodes are checked accordingly.

```
private void CheckChildTreeNodes(IEnumerable<TreeNode> childnodes, ICollection<int> remId)
    {
       if (childnodes==null)
       {
          return;
       }
        foreach (TreeNode node in childnodes)
        {
            if (remId.Contains(node.Tag))
            {
                node.IsChecked = true;
            }
            this.CheckChildTreeNodes(node.Children, remId);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With your helps I have just solve my problem .

```
private void chechTreeViewItems(List<int> remID)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < remID.Count; i++)
        {

            foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode item in this.tvRemark.Nodes[0].Nodes)
            {

                if (Convert.ToInt16(item.Tag) == remID[i])
                {
                    item.Checked = true;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```